# URL path to set class in A element using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, url, navigation, alert

I'm trying to get a dual layers navigation to work. Everything is cool but the jQuery that sets the class `current` to the right A element according to what the URL is. But not even the alert is working, and I'm not sure why (new to jQuery).

as it currently is: [Remote Test Site](http://gulfinsight.obmon.com)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // url
    var $path = location.pathname.split("/");
    var $topnav_path = path[1];
    var $filternav_path = path[2];

    // current page
    var $test = "the category is: " + $topnav_path + " AND the filter is: " + $filternav_path;
    alert($test);

    // navigation
    $(function() {
        // set link to current page
        if ( $path[1] ) {
            $('#top_nav a[class$="' + $topnav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
        }
        // if link is root, set first child (home)
        if ( !$path[1] ) {
            $('#top_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
        }

        // set filter to current filter
        if ( $path[2] ) {
            $('#filter_nav a[class$="' + $filternav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
        }
        // if link is root, set first child (home)
        if ( !$path[2] ) {
            $('#filter_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

The following, as per the first answer below, also doesn't work (with or without the function call):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // url
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        topnav_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        filternav_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false;

    // test url
    var test = "the category is: " + topnav_path + " AND the filter is: " + filternav_path;
    alert(test);

    // navigation
    $(function() {
        // set top nav to current category or home
        if ( path[1] ) {
            $('#top_nav a[class$="' + topnav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
        }else{
            $('#top_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
        }
        // set filter nav to current filter or all
        if ( path[2] ) {
            $('#filter_nav a[class$="' + filternav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
        }else{
            $('#filter_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: At the very least the alert should print something out.. but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `$test` variable, you named it `test`. Same goes for the other variables.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var path = location.pathname.split("/"),
        topnav_path = path[1] != undefined ? path[1] : false,
        filternav_path = path[2] != undefined ? path[2] : false;

    var test = "the category is: " + topnav_path + " AND the filter is: " + filternav_path;

    if ( path[1] ) {
        $('#top_nav a[class$="' + topnav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
    }else{
        $('#top_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
    }

    if ( path[2] ) {
        $('#filter_nav a[class$="' + filternav_path + '"]').toggleClass('current');
    }else{
        $('#filter_nav a:first').toggleClass('current');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Tried your code.. without the $ signs and cleaner, but still doesn't work.. not even the alert.

Comment: Nope.. perhaps I can't target class elements? This part?: a[class$="' +

Comment: Try just doing `console.log(window.location.pathname.split('/'));` and use the console (F12) for debugging, not alerts.

Comment: Very, very strange. It said there was an illegal character at the very end. And there was some weird hidden character at the end, I need two backspaces to delete the last semicolon of the script.. something.. anyway. it works. beautiful. thanks!